# Mock dependency being initialized with new instance inside constructor

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I'm writing test for a class say Producer:

```
public class Producer {
     ProducerConfig config;
     Repo repo;
     Branch branch;
     .......
     
     @Autowired
     public Producer(Service, repo, branch....) {
         config = new Config(service, branch);
     }

}
```

So, the dependency in my Producer class is actually being fulfilled by another instance (service) which initialises my ProducerConfig with a new instance instead of a mock.
The way I am doing is incorrect and I'm not sure if mocking a constructor would work here like I've shown in next snippet.

How do I get the same mocked ProducerConfig that is being generated in test class and assign it in the Producer constructor?

Test class:

```
public class ProducerTest {

      @MockBean ProducerConfig config;
      @MockBean Repo repo;
      @MockBean Branch branch;

      Producer producer;
 
      @BeforeEach
      public void init() {
           Service service = Mockito.mock(Service ,class);
           Mockito.doReturn(config).when(new Config(service, branch));
           this.producer = new Producer(service, repo, branch);
      }

}
```

Comment: Can you add a second constructor to your class?  One where the config is one of the parameters?

Comment: Yes @DawoodibnKareem , I am also trying that. But does changing base code make sense for accommodating test cases?

Comment: In my opinion, yes it does.  Testability is an important property of production code.  So much so that I consider lack of testability to be a bug, and I fix it whenever possible.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to look for other preferable option but this would work too, thanks.

Comment: There is one more thing, the current constructor is @Autowired and hence I can't do the same for the new parametrized constructor. Now I want to use the Producer being created using some values that are being passed in the original constructor. 
How can I achieve it in this case ?